# Calling a parent method from outside the child

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a bunch of `class` objects which all inherit from a base class.  Some of them override a method (`save`) and do stuff.  For this particular use case I want to temporarily not allow the child `save` method to be used (if it exists) but rather force the use of the parent `save` method.

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Base Called")

class Foo(BaseClass):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do_stuff
        print("Foo called")
        return super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

obj = Foo()
```

How can I call `obj` parent save from outside the child such that it prints "Base Called"?

Comment: What do you mean? You mean *only* print "Base Called"?

Comment: Basically ignore the child save method completely and only do the parent method

Comment: You could always do `BaseClass.save(obj)`. Or use `super` if you want it to be more general. Although, this **screams** "I shouldn't be using inheritance"

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: Sure the context is django models. I want to ignore (temporarily) and business that the child models may introduce. This is part of a data merge and I just want the parent save called

Comment: See [`class super([type[, object-or-type]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) for python3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can call methods from an objects parent with `super()`

```
super(type(obj), obj).save()
```

When I run this:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Base Called")

class Foo(BaseClass):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do_stuff
        print("Foo called")
        return super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

obj = Foo()
super(type(obj), obj).save()
```

The output:

```
Base Called
```

Comment: Dumb question does that work even if it's been initialized?

Comment: I think so, edited the answer with the code that I ran to test.